# Saving Edited document back to server with WebDav for Domino

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, webdav

With the Round-trip Editing Library for Domino [WebDAV for IBM Domino](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/WebDAV%20for%20IBM%20Domino) on openntf. after confiuration i was able to download attachment edit but unable to save the document back to the server.

When ever i try to save the document. it prompt me the msg

> "Error saving the document..: The object cannot be created in
>   directory."webdav://server/webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC‌​1258018004E4710/doc.‌​odt

any idea how to go about  it or do i need any extension or plugin for Microsoft Office or open office as well?

Comment: Did you install the helper app? And does the user you use have either editor access to the database or author access to the document? First thing to check: can you make Explorer (the file manager, not IE) show the folder?

Comment: When you manually open a document from OpenOffice or MS Office, the URL you provide in the file open dialog must start with http(s)://, not WebDAV:// - the helper app translates that from WebDAV to http before opening the document. The server app doesn't know anything about WebDAV:// - that's a client side protocol. Communication is via http(s) only.

Comment: yes i did all that the actual error was"Error saving the document..: 
The object cannot be created in directory.
"http:// localhost/webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC‌​1258018004E4710/doc.‌​odt"  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RS2hY.jpg

Comment: The implementation supports editing existing documents. The initial use case never included creating new documents. But I presume you were editing a document. Did you  have a look at the log - anything interesting in there?

Comment: in the log file is CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /webdav/filedemo/1AE86876842E2B4DC1258018004E4710/doc.odt - HTTP Code: 500java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ibm.xsp.webdav.WebDavServlet.service(WebDavServlet.java:317)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
 at ...........

Comment: I have uploaded The print from log here http://i.stack.imgur.com/9otse.jpg

Comment: Hmm. That line is part of an error routine. The tracelog might have more info. You might need to entertain a debug session. Source is on OpenNTF

Comment: i think is missing the com.ibm.domino.osgi.core.context.ContextInfo class

Comment: ContextInfo is a core Domino class. Unless your installation is damaged that would be strange. More likely the method class might be missing. like the PUT.class. Did you build the plugins from source?

Comment: no i use the plugin that is already present  in the zip file

Comment: can u look dis tru Team Viewer?